# polynomial equations of degree 4

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I got this polynomial equations of degree 4 $$x^{4}-6x^{3}-36x^2+216x-324=0$$ from [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem) and i'm tired to solve it without using WF or any software calculator

I even read solution of  [Is there a general formula for solving 4th degree equations (quartic)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations) but looks like hard

Comment: If you know that the roots are integers,  you can make use of vietas formulas. E.g. For the case of degree 2 if the roots are $a$ and $b$, the polynomial is $(x-a)(x-b) = x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ so you know the constant term is the product of all four solutions, etc. In your case you have $-324 = -2^2\cdot 3^4$. There fore you know that one or three roots have negative coefficients, and the only ones possible, are divisors of $324$.

Comment: @flawr: But here the roots are not integers: there is one between $-7$ and $-6$ and another between $7$ and $8$.

Comment: Well then I do not think that there is an easier way of finding the roots, tan using the general formula from galois theory or any numerical methods (e.g. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) )

Comment: could you do it by using the Galois Theory

Comment: See [quartic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: @Educ - How sure are you that you derived the correct quartic equation above - it might be worthwhile stating the original problem in full.

Comment: @Mufasa see my update

Comment: @Educ This question now has an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1, just let $x=h_j$.