# Analytical solution to the crossed ladders problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polynomials, nonlinear-system, quartics

I'm working on an analytical solution to the crossed ladders problem.
The solution is almost done and already useable (see my answer to [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem) for details).
However I'm left with a problem in the end: depending on which ladder I choose using to calculate $w$, the expression of $w$ seems not to be the same.
Let $\left(j,k\right)\in\lbrace\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right)\rbrace$, $m\in\lbrace1,2,3,4\rbrace$, and $n\in\lbrace-,+\rbrace$.
Any quantity with a $j$ or $k$ index below seems to depend on the choice of the ladder while, in all numerical applications I tried, I always have $w_{jmn}=w_{kmn}$ with $w_{jmn}=n\sqrt{l_k^2-h_{jm}^2}$ and $w_{kmn}=n\sqrt{l_j^2-h_{km}^2}$.
This leads to:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
w_{j1+}&=\frac{\sqrt{R_9+R_7+c_F}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{c_{jL}\sqrt{R_9-R_7-c_F}}{6}\\
w_{j1-}&=\frac{-\sqrt{R_9+R_7+c_F}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{-c_{jL}\sqrt{R_9-R_7-c_F}}{6}\\
w_{j2+}&=\frac{\sqrt{R_9+R_7+c_F}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{c_{jM}\sqrt{R_9-R_7-c_F}}{6}\\
w_{j2-}&=\frac{-\sqrt{R_9+R_7+c_F}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{-c_{jM}\sqrt{R_9-R_7-c_F}}{6}\\
w_{j3+}&=\frac{c_{jN}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right|}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{c_{jO}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right|}}{6}\\
w_{j3-}&=\frac{-c_{jN}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right|}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{-c_{jO}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right|}}{6}\\
w_{j4+}&=\frac{c_{jP}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right|}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{c_{jQ}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right|}}{6}\\
w_{j4-}&=\frac{-c_{jP}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right|}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{-c_{jQ}\sqrt{\left|2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right|}}{6}\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

With (again see the answer to [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem) for all details):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R_{j8}&=6\ \text{sgn}\left(3h+R_{j2}\right)\sqrt{2c_G-R_6+12\left|h\right|^3\sqrt{
\begin{split}
&36h^2-6\sqrt[3]{27h^2c_{jA}^2+3c_{jA}^2\sqrt{c_H}}\\
&-6\sqrt[3]{27h^2c_{jA}^2-3c_{jA}^2\sqrt{c_H}}\\
\end{split}
}}\\
c_{jL}&=1-\left(-1\right)^j\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)-\left|\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)\right|\\
c_{jM}&=1+\left(-1\right)^j\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)-\left|\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)\right|\\
c_{jN}&=\frac{1+\ \text{sgn}\left(2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right)}{2}\\
c_{jO}&=\frac{1-\ \text{sgn}\left(2c_F-2R_7+R_{j8}\right)}{2}\\
c_{jP}&=\frac{1+\ \text{sgn}\left(2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right)}{2}\\
c_{jQ}&=\frac{1-\ \text{sgn}\left(2c_F-2R_7-R_{j8}\right)}{2}\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

Thus I wonder if it is possible to prove that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R_{k8}&=R_{j8}\\
c_{kL}&=c_{jL}\\
c_{kM}&=c_{jM}\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

$R_{k8}=R_{j8}$ would imply $c_{kN}=c_{jN}$, $c_{kO}=c_{jO}$, $c_{kP}=c_{jP}$, and $c_{kQ}=c_{jQ}$.
Proving $\ \text{sgn}\left(3h+R_{k2}\right)=\ \text{sgn}\left(3h+R_{j2}\right)$ would be enough to prove all these relations.
For $c_{kL}=c_{jL}$ and $c_{kM}=c_{jM}$, proving $\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{k2}\right)=-\ \text{sgn}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)$ would be enough.
In my attempts, and when working on the general solution, I came across the following equations, which I write in case they are helpful:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R_{j1}^3&=27c_{jA}^2R_{j1}+54c_{jC}\\
R_{j2}R_{j3}&=54\left(hc_{jA}+h^3\right)\\
R_{j3}&=2\sqrt{R_{j1}^2+c_{jB}R_{j1}+9c_{jA}^2-108h^2c_{jA}+81h^4}\\
R_6&=\frac{R_{j1}^2+6c_{jA}R_{j1}-18c_{jA}^2}{9}\\
R_7&=\frac{6hR_{j2}+R_{j3}}{2}\\
R_{j8}&=2R_{j4}\left(3h+R_{j2}\right)\\
R_9&=\sqrt{\left(c_F+R_7\right)^2+R_{j5}^2\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)^2}\\
R_{j1}&\geq6c_{jA}-9h^2\\
R_{k1}&=-R_{j1}\\
\text{sgn}\left(R_{j1}\right)&=\ \text{sgn}\left(c_{jA}\right)\\
hc_{jA}+h^3=0&\implies R_{j1}-c_{jB}=0\\
R_{j3}&\geq\left|R_{j1}+12c_{jA}-18h^2\right|\\
R_{j3}&\geq-6hR_{j2}\\
R_{j5}=0&\implies3h-R_{j2}=0
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof by counterexample, so there might be a better one.
The system $\left(1\right)$ of the answer to [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem?rq=1) gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0&=h\left(h_j+h_k\right)-h_jh_k\\
0&=h_j^2-h_k^2+c_{jA}\\
\end{split}
\tag{8}
\end{equation}

Let the real numbers:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(S_{j4},S_{j5}\right)&\in\lbrace\left(-1,0\right),\left(0,-1\right),\left(0,1\right),\left(1,0\right)\rbrace\\
\left(S_{k4},S_{k5}\right)&\in\lbrace\left(-1,0\right),\left(0,-1\right),\left(0,1\right),\left(1,0\right)\rbrace\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

According to $\left(7\right)$ of the answer to [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem?rq=1), the general expressions of $h_j$ and $h_k$ are:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
h_j&=\frac{3h+\left(S_{j4}^2-S_{j5}^2\right)R_{j2}+S_{j4}R_{j4}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{S_{j5}R_{j5}}{6}\\
h_k&=\frac{3h+\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)R_{k2}+S_{k4}R_{k4}}{6}+\text{i}\frac{S_{k5}R_{k5}}{6}\\
\end{split}
\tag{9}
\end{equation}

Combining $\left(8\right)$ and $\left(9\right)$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&S_{j4}R_{j4}\left(3h-\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)R_{k2}\right)+S_{k4}R_{k4}\left(3h-\left(S_{j4}^2-S_{j5}^2\right)R_{j2}\right)\\
&=S_{j4}S_{k4}R_{j4}R_{k4}-S_{j5}S_{k5}R_{j5}R_{k5}+\left(S_{j4}^2-S_{j5}^2\right)\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)R_{j2}R_{k2}\\
&-\left(S_{j4}^2-S_{j5}^2\right)3hR_{j2}-\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)3hR_{k2}-27h^2\\
&S_{j5}R_{j5}\left(3h-\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)R_{k2}\right)+S_{k5}R_{k5}\left(3h-\left(S_{j4}^2-S_{j5}^2\right)R_{j2}\right)\\
&=S_{j4}S_{k5}R_{j4}R_{k5}+S_{k4}S_{j5}R_{k4}R_{j5}\\
&S_{j4}R_{j4}\left(3h+R_{j2}\right)-S_{k4}R_{k4}\left(3h+R_{k2}\right)=\left(S_{k4}^2-S_{j4}^2+S_{j5}^2-S_{k5}^2\right)R_7\\
&S_{j5}R_{j5}\left(3h-R_{j2}\right)-S_{k5}R_{k5}\left(3h-R_{k2}\right)=0\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

Many counterexamples can be found for these equations if $S_{k4}\neq S_{j4}$ or $S_{k5}\neq S_{j5}$.
The one given in [Crossed Ladders Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem?rq=1), $\left(h,l_j,l_k\right)=\left(3,8,10\right)$, is one of them.
Thus:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_{k4}&=S_{j4}\\
S_{k5}&=S_{j5}\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}

Thus each $h_{km}$ corresponds to each $h_{jm}$, and thus:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R_{k8}=R_{j8}&=R_8\\
c_{kL}=c_{jL}&=c_L\\
c_{kM}=c_{jM}&=c_M\\
w_{kmn}=w_{jmn}&=w_{mn}\\
\end{split}
\notag
\end{equation}